# Is a function in $C^1 _0(D)$ times a function in $H^1 _{loc} \cap L^2 (D)$ in $C^{\infty}_{0}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Is the product of a function in $C^1 _0(D)$ times a function in $H^1 _{loc} \cap L^2 (D)$ in $C^{\infty}_{0}$?

I understand that the compact support carries over pretty simply. Since we have one function that's $0$ outside the domain involved in the product it's clear that the product will also be $0$ outside the domain.

The part I'm confused on is how we can get a result that is infinitely differentiable. I can reason to myself that at most it should be twice continuously differentiable but I'm not sure where to go from here. Any hints/thoughts/ or even ideas of illuminating examples are appreciated. For the life of me I can't even find good example functions to help myself visualize this better.

Comment: Of course, the claim is as wrong as it can be. You are right with your suspicions.

Comment: @daw Thank you! I thought I was missing something.